# OnCollisonEnter(Collision other) doesn`t detect my object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity VR in which I punch numbers and get points.

[image: Screenshot]

The gloves are responsible for detecting collisions between the numbers that they hit. On my gloves I have a `PunchScript` component and the numbers each have a `rigidBody` and `collider`.

The problem is that no collisions seem to ever occur. I placed a `Debug.LogError` inside of the collision detection code to assert this.

I tried switching on/off kinematics on all objects and used different collision systems to no avail.

Here's my `PunchScript` component:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PunchScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SteamVR_TrackedObject hand; 
    private Rigidbody rBody;
    private bool visible = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();  
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rBody.MovePosition(hand.transform.position);
        rBody.MoveRotation(hand.transform.rotation);

       // print(rBody.velocity.magnitude* 1000);
    }

    void OnCollisonEnter(Collision other) 
    {
        Rigidbody otherR = other.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody>();

        if (other.gameObject.name == "frpnchbg") {
            Debug.LogError("Hit!");
        }

        if (other == null)
            return;

        Vector3 avgPoint = Vector3.zero;

        foreach (ContactPoint p in other.contacts) {
            avgPoint += p.point;
        }

        avgPoint /= other.contacts.Length;

        Vector3 dir = (avgPoint - transform.position).normalized;
        otherR.AddForceAtPosition(dir *50f* rBody.velocity.magnitude, avgPoint);
    }
}
```

Here's how the glove object looks in the Unity inspector.

[image: Unity inspector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very important to write the name of Unity callback methods correctly, otherwise Unity will not be able to detect them on the object (and as a result, can never execute them).

In your case, you have misspelled the [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) callback.
Instead of `OnCollisonEnter` it should be `OnCollisionEnter`.